# Replacing Chr(10) with Chr(13) + Chr(10) in Excel for import into Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

The issue is that line breaks in Excel use `Char(10)`, but in Access they use `Char(13) & Char(10)`. Thus, when you import in to Access from Excel, what were line breaks in Excel, are all on the same line in Access.

I have imports automated with a button click so that some of the data can be sanitized before input. I want to add this to the sensitization, but I'm having trouble with it:

```
' Remove blank cells that aren't blank (i.e., pasting values of formulas with no value)
xl.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
xl.Selection.Value = xl.Selection.Value

' Replace line breaks and carriage returns with something Access recognizes
xl.Selection.Value = Replace(xl.Selection.Value, Chr(10), Chr(13) + Chr(10))

' OR this....

xl.ActiveSheet.Selection.Replace _
  What:=Chr(10), Replacement:=Chr(13) + Chr(10), _
  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False
```

The first approach generates:

```
Run-time error '13': Type mismatch
```

The second approach generates:

```
Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Where am I going wrong here and what would be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, figured it out a few minutes after posting:

```
xl.Selection.Replace What:="" & Chr(10) & "", Replacement:="" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the Excel data, you could alternatively run the following query following the import into MS Access:

```sql
update 
    YourTable t 
set 
    t.YourField = Replace(t.YourField, Chr(10), Chr(13) & Chr(10))
where 
    t.YourField like "*" & Chr(10) & "*" and
    t.YourField not like "*" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "*"
```